# Is there a javascript (ES6 +) equivalent for Typescript's namespace

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I wonder if there is an equivalent for Typescript's namespace to use nested namespaces in javascript ?

example :

```
export {Classname as My.Name.Classname}

// or 
export namespace My.Name {  
     class Classname {
     }
}
```

Comment: [Copy that into the TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAOwIYFtgGcxIMbDgWQE8A6AOVTwG844AoGh7AGyXXTgGEW3k05L6DOAF9awoA), observe the resulting JavaScript on the right...

Comment: I didn't say that's an actual working code. I want its equivalent

Comment: *I* didn't say that's an actual working code. The JavaScript produced by the TypeScript compiler is, by definition, its exact equivalent.